# ImportError: No module named PloneTestCase

Tags: unit-testing, plone

I run unit test in plone 5 based on this [documentation](http://docs.plone.org/manage/deploying/testing_tuning/testing_and_debugging/unit_testing.html#id2) . However when I executed this command :

```
bin/test
```

I got the following import error:

```
Test-module import failures:

Module: nti.content.tests

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/ega/CMS/PloneCourseContentCMF/PloneCourseContentCMF-Buildout/sources/nti.content/nti/content/tests.py", line 8, in <module>
        from Products.PloneTestCase import PloneTestCase as ptc
    ImportError: No module named PloneTestCase

    Test-modules with import problems:
      nti.content.tests
    Total: 0 tests, 0 failures, 0 errors in 0.000 seconds.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: It's important to realize that Plone 5 is in beta 1. Or, you may be using a core checkout. Questions like this are best raised on the development list, as the answers are unlikely to have any long-term value -- and are poorly suited to stackoverflow.

Comment: For reference: Plone unit testing documentation has moved to https://docs.plone.org/develop/testing/unit_testing.html. There is also information inside the Plone training: https://training.plone.org/5/testing/unittest.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Plone [recently removed](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/issues/388) its dependency on PloneTestCase.

So you should either do the same and port to [plone.app.testing](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.testing) or add PloneTestCase on your [test] extras on setup.py, i.e.

```
setup(
    ...
    extras_require=dict(
        test=[
            'Products.PloneTestCase',
        ]
    ),
)
```

Comment: I tried to add PloneTestCase as you suggested above however after running buildout, I still got the same error.

Comment: Make sure you add <PACKAGE NAME> [test] in your buildout.cfg to actually load your test extras that you have defined.

Comment: great! adding extra_require in setup.py and  <PRODUCT NAME> [test] in buildout.cfg solve this import error. Thanks